# Batch put start arguments into a new line

Tags: windows, batch-file

Created a batch file to start a program with arguments. Work fine. I like to put `test5.coffe` and `test2.coffe` into separated lines. Here is my problem. It do not take the arguments anymore. Is there a way around it ?

**Working Example**

```
start "" "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm\coffee.cmd" --join test.js --compile test5.coffe test2.coffe
```

**Not working Example**

```
start "" "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm\coffee.cmd" --join test.js --compile 
test5.coffe 
test2.coffe
```

Comment: For clarity, You're compiling test5 and test2 into test.js and you can't do it twice just using test5 or test2 as the --compile parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
rem -- do not leave empty spaces after the ^s
start "" "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm\coffee.cmd" --join test.js --compile ^
test5.coffe ^
test2.coffe
```